# combine two data.frame cols without creating a new col. r

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations

Let's say I have

```
one <- mtcars[1:4, ]
two <- mtcars[1:7, ]
```

All I need to get is this; in a one big beautiful df without adding another col that resulted by rbind(), rbind.fill(), union() etc.

```
>    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> 1 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> 2 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> 2 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> 3 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> 3 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> 4 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> 4 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> 5 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#> 6 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#> 7 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
```

I know its probably a simple commend but it's giving me a hard time to figure out, Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. "rbind(one,two)" gives the output you want.

Comment: rbind() works only with the equal length of two cols, isn't it?

Comment: No, it works with any number of rows, but the two elements need to have same number of columns.

Comment: Ok, Thanks I get this error: Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names

Comment: If you are getting that error, then you are not testing against the test-data you provided above. The names in the two sets of columns need to match.

Comment: If the names don't match you'll need something that fills columns such as `data.table`s `rbindlist` or the `rbind.fill` that you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
one <- mtcars[1:4, ]
two <- mtcars[1:7, ]

rbind(one,two)
```